# Is quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(\langle (4,6)\rangle)$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(\langle (4,6)\rangle)$ cyclic? I'm not sure but I tried to prove that this is equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}$. It does not work and I'm really stuck now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1=(2,3)$ and $v_2=(1,1)$.
Then $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}v_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2$ 
because $\begin{vmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 \end{vmatrix} = -1$

and so
$$
(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(\langle (4,6)\rangle)
= (\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})/(2\mathbb{Z}v_1)
= (\mathbb{Z}v_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2) / (2\mathbb{Z}v_1 \oplus 0)
\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}
$$
is infinite and not cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $2 \cdot\overline{(2,3)} = 0$ in the quotient. So if it were cyclic, it would need to be finite, in particular it can't be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Sorry how is $2 \cdot (<(2,3)>)$ in the quotient?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to denote the equivalence class, I fixed it.

Comment: Expansion on the hint: $\overline{(2,3)}$ is a torsion element of the quotient group as shown above, and $\overline{(1,0)}$ is a non-torsion element.  Is it possible for a cyclic group to have both torsion and non-torsion elements?

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using this "torsion" concept; we have just covered quotient group and Isomorphism theorems.

Comment: "Torsion" is just a fancy name for what happens in a group (most often applied in the context of abelian groups) with $x \ne 0$ but $n \cdot x = 0$ for some $x \in G$, $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: Be careful,  $\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed cyclic. Then an element is a torsion one if its order is finite ($0$ is indeed always a torsion element)

Comment: @Tancredi I did not claim that $\Bbb Z$ is not cyclic. I was impyling that there is a non-zero torsion element.

Comment: Now I got your hint, you're right